# Null Pointer exception occurred while doing Rythm.init(Map<String,Object> map)

Tags: java, rythm

I am new to Rythm template engine, trying to access the external file and render the data but unable to success. having 'Null Pointer exception'
when trying to do the Rythm.init(Map map).
I followed the same steps which are provided in the tutorial. Please find the below link.

http://rythmengine.org/doc/tutorial.md

I am using : **rythm-engine-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT**

```
Error :
init:

compile:
  [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\rythm-tutorial\HelloWorld\classes

n:
   [java] java.lang.NullPointerException
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava
ava:194)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)

   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)

   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.ja
:291)
   [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc

   [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchU
ls.java:106)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.jav
1399)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)

   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(De
ultExecutor.java:41)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251

   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
   [java] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   [java]     at org.rythmengine.resource.TemplateResourceManager.<init>(Templ
eResourceManager.java:168)
   [java]     at org.rythmengine.RythmEngine.init(RythmEngine.java:636)
   [java]     at org.rythmengine.RythmEngine.<init>(RythmEngine.java:561)
   [java]     at org.rythmengine.Rythm.init(Rythm.java:97)
   [java]     at HelloWorld.main(Unknown Source)
   [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc

   [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.jav
217)
```

**Java code :**

```
import org.rythmengine.Rythm;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("home.template","resources");
        Rythm.init(map);
        System.out.println(Rythm.render("helloworld.html","world"));    
    }
}
```

Request for help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you pass a null map? Post your code.

Comment: Please find below code :                                                                             public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
  map.put("home.template","resources");
  Rythm.init(map);
     System.out.println(Rythm.render("helloworld.html","world")); 
    }
}

Comment: Post it in the question.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce it, I do however, get an NPE from the `Rythm.render()` call. (At least when I call it with a File() argument). Considering the Javadoc doesn't note for what an NPE can be thrown (in both cases)... file a bug report?

Comment: Also, are you using the latest version?

Comment: I am using latest version of the Rythm i.e,: rythm-engine-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT and running through ANT .                                                                    Also could you please tell me which version of Rythm your using hence I will try and see is the issue reproducible or not

Comment: This was with maven LATEST which translates to 1.0.1.

Comment: Could you please let me know from where do I need to download the latest Rythm template jar which works and I need to run from ANT. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please download the latest Rythm from http://rythmengine.org/doc/index.md#get. And let me know your result

Comment: Could you able to fix this issue? I'm also getting a NPE at the line rythmEngine.render()